# user session discrepancy across subdomains pointing to the same DNS name

Tags: django, azure, dns, no-www

I maintain a Python/Django web app where users can authenticate and log in. I've noticed that if I log into my app at `example.com`, I'm still logged out at `www.example.com`!

This behavior replicates on all major browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc). It seems session information is not being maintained between these addresses? I'm perplexed. Why could this be happening?

---

My DNS name was procured from Azure. E.g. `example.cloudapp.net`. I use a DNS management service called [Hurricane Electric](https://dns.he.net/) to map `example.com` and `www.example.com` to this DNS name. Specifically, in Hurricane Electric I've created CNAME records where the hostname is the azure-provided DNS name, and the name is the web address I want to associate with it (along with a TTL). That's about all I've done.

PROPOSED FIX: in my DNS management system, should I route `www.example.com` to `example.com` intead of `example.cloudapp.net`?

---

Note: Explored whether this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116860/django-session-cookie-domain-with-multiple-domains) can solve my problem. It ostensibly does, but a known issue is losing all session information - and I do NOT want that.

Comment: Yeah, the answer you linked is probably the reason you are having trouble. Your authentication cookie is probably set to a single domain. You can confirm this from your F12 tools.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused about how to set the cookie to multiple (sub)domains. I.e. shouldn't I set it to the original host `example.cloudapp.net` that `example.com` and `www.example.com` are pointing to? OR should I set the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to `.example.com` and be done with it?

Comment: Added some new information to the question.