# How to share Django sessions across newly added subdomains

Tags: django, django-sessions

I've recently added some new subdomains (e.g `x.example.com`) to my django site (all under the same app), and I'd like users to stay logged in across these subdomains.

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN), I can simply set the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting to be `".example.com"` to do this, but the docs mention this warning:

> Be cautious when updating this setting on a production site. If you update this setting to enable cross-domain cookies on a site that previously used standard domain cookies, existing user cookies will be set to the old domain. This may result in them being unable to log in as long as these cookies persist.

Given that I'm currently using standard domain cookies, this certainly applies to me! However, the docs offer no solution.

How can I switch the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to be cross-domain without messing up my existing users' sessions (and ideally, without forcing them to log out)?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116860/django-session-cookie-domain-with-multiple-domains

Comment: @T.Tokic The answers there just seem to suggest using `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".example.com"`, I believe. 

I know that I need to do that; my question is specifically about how to switch to that setting without my existing users"being unable to log in", as the django docs mention will happen.

Answer (score 4):

To gracefully change the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`, without existing users getting affected, you can change the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` to a new name. By default, it is set to `sessionid`. If you set this to some other name like `newsessionid`, all the existing users will have to re-login, since the new cookie will not be present in their requests.

Read more about this in the Django docs [SESSION_COOKIE_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name).