# Different SESSION_COOKIE_AGE for Different Domain or APP

Tags: django

I have 2 app in one django project. I allow two Domain(e.g. aaa.com & bbb.com) to access my django project. (Actually, aaa.com to app A, bbb.com to app B). 
(There is some reasons that I want to create 2 app in 1 project.)

And I want to set different SESSION_COOKIE_AGE for these 2 domains. So I'm thinking about these solutions...

---

(Solution A)

aaa.com - SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 10 (domain & age are just an example)

bbb.com - SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 20

or

(Solution B)

App A - SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 10

App B - SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 20

Is django support it?

---

If NOT,
Since I use this code to create a cookies in views.py for App A,

```
request.session._get_or_create_session_key()
request.session.modified = True
```

Can I specific cookies age in views.py which overwrite the setting in settings.py?

I'm using django 2.0.2

Thanks!

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116860/django-session-cookie-domain-with-multiple-domains