# One Django app instance for multiple domains

Tags: python, django, django-sites

I try to create an Django app which will work for multiple domains with single app instance.

For example:

- there are three domains: *group1.com, group2.com, group3.com*
- each domain has restricted content available after login
- user1 is associated with *group1.com* and *group2.com*
- when *user1* log in to *group1.com* and try to enter *group2.com*, he will be automatically log in into the *group2.com*
- there is URL, e.g. *DOMAIN_NAME/posts/* which will show all content for user which is logged in from all domains which are associated with this user (in this case, for *user1* there should be all "posts" from *group1.com* and *group2.com*)
- when *user1* enter *group3.com*, he's not logged in

I used Django Site framework to associate user with domains - content restriction for user in specific domains works fine.

Additionally, I used *SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN* parameter in *settings.py* for "share" cookie between domains and, unfortunately, it only works for subdomains. For example, after set:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.group.com'
```

and after I wrote simple middleware, I'm able to meet the requirements that I wrote above but only for subdomains, like '*one.group.com*', '*two.group.com*', '*three.group.com*'.

I was looking for solution for handle that, but I haven't found an answer for newest Django 3.x framework.

Is there any way to handle that like I explained?

Comment: How about using a custom middleware along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6728654/1388292

Answer (score 2):

I think "[django-hosts](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts)" package for you.

Firstly, you should give permission some domain.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [example1.com,example2.com,example3.com]
```

And than, you can use [django-hosts](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts)

```
from django_hosts import patterns, host
host_patterns = patterns('path.to',
    host(r'api', 'api.urls', name='api'),
    host(r'beta', 'beta.urls', name='beta'),
)
```

You can see more information -> https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts